# Confusion over creating RxJava2 reactive streams with .create()

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java2

The various RxJava2 streams (`Single`, `Maybe` etc.--I'll refer to them as `Xxx`) have a static method `.create( XxxOnSubscribe onSubscribe )`. The `XxxOnSubscribe` object passed is supposed to implement the method `void subscribe( XxxEmitter emitter )`.

An `Emitter` seems to be like an `Observer` but with a few differences (it's not exactly an extension of `Observer`):

- its `.subscribe()` method returns `void` instead of a `Disposable`
- it lacks an `.onSubscribe()` method (which returns a `Disposable`)
- it adds methods `.setCancellable()`, `.setDisposable()`, `.isDisposed()`, and `.tryOnError()`.

The docs say "The emitter implementations will dispose/cancel this instance (what instance?) when the downstream cancels the flow or after the event generator logic calls `onSuccess(Object)`, `onError(Throwable)`, `onComplete()` or when `tryOnError(Throwable)` succeeds."

Among my questions about this:

- Why can't an `Xxx` be created with a normal `Observer` with a `.subscribe()` returning a `Disposable`?
- Why was `.onSubscribe()` eliminated from `Emitter`?
- What is the rationale for requiring an `Emitter`?
- When would you use a `Cancellable` vs. a `Disposable`?
- How does the addition of `.tryOnError()` help things?

Is there a fuller explanation of this scheme available?

(Possibly related: my Android app seems to be experiencing some odd behavior of the `.retry()` operator. Does `.retry()` call `.dispose()` upstream before attempting to resubscribe?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what instance?

Should be clear from the context of the [preceding sentence in the docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/MaybeEmitter.html):

> The emitter allows the registration of a single resource, in the form of a `Disposable` or `Cancellable` via `setDisposable(Disposable)` or `setCancellable(Cancellable)` respectively. The emitter implementations will dispose/cancel this instance when the downstream cancels the flow or after the event generator logic calls `onSuccess(Object)`, `Emitter.onError(Throwable)`, `Emitter.onComplete()` or when `tryOnError(Throwable)` succeeds.

The instance of a `Disposable` or `Cancellable`.

> Why can't an Xxx be created with a normal Observer

We don't want the user to call the `onSubscribe` method as it has no use in the operators. We can't hide methods so we designed a separate interface with only the supported methods.

> with a .subscribe() returning a Disposable?

Because of the so-called synchronous cancellation problem. If your method never returns for some reason, it can't return a `Disposable` and the downstream has no means to cancel the flow.

> Why was .onSubscribe() eliminated from Emitter

There is no reason to call it as the operator will handle the call to `Observer.onSubscribe` for the downstream for you before the `subscribe` method of the emitter implementation gets invoked.

> What is the rationale for requiring an Emitter?

API design. We provide a clear set of methods that can be called without exposing methods that should not or would not work anyway.

> When would you use a Cancellable vs. a Disposable?

Please read the [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/Cancellable.html) and signature. Use whichever is convenient for your resource cancellation needs.

> How does the addition of .tryOnError() help things?

Please read the [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/FlowableEmitter.html#tryOnError-java.lang.Throwable-).

> Is there a fuller explanation of this scheme available?

Please see each example in the various method [javadocs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html#create-io.reactivex.MaybeOnSubscribe-).

> Does .retry() call .dispose() upstream before attempting to resubscribe?

In theory, there is no need to call `dispose` when an error has been received but the current implementation may do it regardless. I have to think about if this needs to change in RxJava or not.

Comment: It's looking to me like any supplied `Disposable` or `Cancellable` gets called even on normal termination of a `Single`. Will be interested to hear your thoughts on this. Do I recall reading somewhere that `.isDisposed()` may or may not return `true` after a termination? Is there a chance of a firm policy on this? Is it possible that there should be _three_ states for the terminal status: normal completion, error, and canceled by client?

Comment: a) That's right. b) It is not guaranteed but sometimes we add this guarantee on user-reported use cases. c) Not likely. d) Makes no sense as people would spinloop for the desired state, defeating the purpose of RxJava.